# MODBUS RTU: Data received is not correct

Tags: modbus, opc

I have a Precia Molen i30 weighing indicator. I am communicating with this indicator via **Modbus 485** using an OPC software (kepware). I have set all the Parameters. According to Manual the Gross Current Weight is on the ADDRESS=256 and data type is 32 bit signed integer. I have set address 300257 or 400257 and data type "Double Word" in my OPC software. With this address communication between my OPC software and weighing indicator is OK but the value coming in my software is not same as displaying on indicator. e.g., 
when value on weighing indicator=0 then value in my Modbus Software=0,
when value on weighing indicator=10 then value in my Modbus Software=655360,
when value on weighing indicator=7160 then value in my Modbus Software=468285400 and when value on weighing indicator=50270 then value in my Modbus Software=3294494720.
Please tell me what might be the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an endianness problem.

When the device indicates 10 (0xa) your Modbus master interprets it as 655360 (0xa0000).

Your OPC server is reading both registers 256 and 257 (because it's a 32-bit variable), but it its concatenating the registers in the wrong order. Check in OPC server manual how to swap the register order, and you'll get the correct values.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ronaldo,